# Retrieving the App.get_running_app().root.ids returns an empty dictionary (Can't retrieve the ids)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to retrieve the ids of the widgets under the MDApp, however I keep getting an empty dictionary printed out. I found that the ids dict wasn't populated after debugging a problem where whenever I try to access any other widget using it's ID I would get an error.

At first, I tried printing the ids out straight in the build function under MDApp, then in the on_start function, and finally tried printing it out by pressing a button:

PS: I tried also printing out the id of the button itself which was defined as ( """ MenuButton: id: Menu_Button "" ) however, that too came back as empty (an empty string space is printed out).

```py
class MenuButton(MDFloatingActionButton):
    def press(self):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        print(app.root.ids)
        print(self.id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ids` dictionary is not part of the `App` instance, they are added to the root widget under which they are defined. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids). The documentation states:

> ids are added to the root widget’s ids dictionary

The `root` widget is the widget in which the `id` is defined in the `kv`, not the `root` widget of the `App` Poor choice of wording by the documenters. The `ids` would only appear in the `App.root` if the `ids` are defined in a `kv` definition for a widget that is actually the `App.root`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it makes sense now why it works in the .kv file but not in the actual code.